# I have an error message while compiling SCSS where it states a } is missing

Tags: sass, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile some pretty simple SCSS but I have an error message I cannot it work out.

```
Error: expected "}".
   ╷
23 │ }
   │  ^
   ╵
  atomonestylesheet.scss 23:2  root stylesheet
```

Above is the error message I received and below is the code.

```
h2 {
  font-family: 'Overpass', monospace;
}
```

23:2 being just after the closing }.

I have tried a few things.

- Adding a } where it asks
- Adding the } and deleting the other
- looking for other people with the same problem

Can I have some help?

Whole file.

```
:root {

  --1: #404E4D; /* Green Gray */
  --2: #8BE8CB; /* Mint */
  --3: #7EA2AA; /* Blue Gray */
  --4: #F3F2F0; /* Whitish */
  --5: #b5bd68; /* Olive*/
  --6: #53917E; /*Teal*/
  --7: #182825; /*VeryDark Turquiose*/
  --8: #a6d1c9; /* Cyan */
  --9: #e83c38; /* Orange-red */
}



h1 {
  color: var(--3);
  font-family: 'Overpass Mono', monospace;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Overpass', monospace;
}




{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-list{
  height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: could you share the full file content?

Comment: I will add that to the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a block rule without any selector that throws this error. remove it or add the proper selector to it to fix the error:

```
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```